# archaic term for the word not

Tags: conjunctions, negation

What is the archaic term for who is not? or words like not and do not or how to make phrases in archaic way that includes “not” does term such exist?

like this,

**i am not aware ** thee brought all four seasons

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "i am not aware thee brought all four seasons" is early modern English, not Old English (or Middle English which had slightly different rules, e.g. "I wot not eysiere lyf than is religioun."). Googling Old English negation gets pages [like this](https://oldenglish.info/negations.html) with constructions like "Ic ne þence" ("not" didn't appear till Middle English) - is that what you want?

Comment: Thankyou for clarifying. It seems I misunderstood what old english is and use it without a proper knowledge and just found out negation is the term used for contradictory words. Thankyou.

Comment: You can't leave out *that* after *aware* for these times.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _thou broughtest_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Early Modern English (which is what you're talking about), negation simply uses "not" after the verb:

> He went not forth.

> They work not there today.

(We still use this for "be" and "have", but for other verbs we have to use "do not").

Similarly questions:

> Goes she to market today?

> Lives he yet in the town?

(Again, we still do this for "be" and "have")

As for your pronouns: "thee" is like "me" or "him" - you could not use it as the subject:

I    me   my/mine

**Thou thee thy/thine**

He   him  his

She  her  her/hers

It   it   his ("its" didn't exist in Shakespeare's day)

We   us   our/ours

**Ye**   you  your/yours

They them their/theirs

And "thou" takes a special verb form, ending in *-(e)st*.

So your example should read:

> I am not aware that **thou broughtest/brought'st/didst bring** all four seasons

Comment: *Broughtest*? Or *didst bring*?

Comment: All three are possible.

Comment: Edited to incorporate possibilities